# How to compare background color in jquery when using if else statement

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to compare background color of a button using an if else statement but it always come out as false.

```js
<script>
           
                
                $('#switchButton').bind('click', function() {
                    var color = $("#switchButton").css("background-color");
                    socket.send(color);
                    $('#messages').append('<li>me: ' + color + '</li>');

                    if (color == 'rgb(0,128,0)')
                        $("#switchButton").css("background-color", "rgb(0,0,0)");
                    else 
                        $("#switchButton").css("background-color", "rgb(255,0,0)");
                        
                });    
            });
        </script>
```

```html
#switchButton{
 background-color: green
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the incorrect value of color. The `rgb` value has a whitespace after each comma so you need to change `color == 'rgb(0,128,0)'` to `color == 'rgb(0, 128, 0)'`

```js
$('#switchButton').bind('click', function() {
  var color = $("#switchButton").css("background-color");
  //socket.send(color);
  $('#messages').append('<li>me: ' + color + '</li>');
  if (color == 'rgb(0, 128, 0)')
    $("#switchButton").css("background-color", "rgb(0,0,0)");
  else 
    $("#switchButton").css("background-color", "rgb(255,0,0)");
});
```

```css
#switchButton{
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='switchButton'>Click me</button>
<div id='messages'></div>
```

Comment: @Onjieee glad to help :)